# List index out of range

Tags: python, list

How do I fix this error, pos_coordinates contains a list of values and the updatePos_coordinates is the previously pos_coordiantes values copied into the updatePos_coordinates list. I want to find the differences between the object and index value 8, 9, 12, and 13. but I kept on getting this error. How do I solve this

```
    screen_width = 0
    screen_height = 0
    updatePos_coordinates = []

    while True:
        client_socket.send("loc\n")
        data = client_socket.recv(8192)
        pos_coordinates = data.split()

        if(not(pos_coordinates[-1] == "eom" and pos_coordinates[0] == "start")):
            continue

        if (screen_width != int(pos_coordinates[2])):
            screen_width = int(pos_coordinates[2])
            screen_height = int(pos_coordinates[3])

        if (pos_coordinates != updatePos_coordinates):
            if(cmp(pos_coordinates[8:10], updatePos_coordinates[8:10]) == 0):
                both.brake()
                print "Ball is in the same location.."
            if((pos_coordinates[8] - updatePos_coordinates[8] > 5) or (pos_coordinates[8] - updatePos_coordinates[8] < -5) or (pos_coordinates[9] - updatePos_coordinates[9] > 5) or (pos_coordinates[9] - updatePos_coordinates[9] < -5)):     
                activateRobot(pos_coordinates)
            else:
                both.brake()
                print "Ball is in the same location.."

        updatePos_coordinates = pos_coordinates[:]
        time.sleep(3)
        print '...........'
```

and I keep on getting this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 155, in <module>
    if((pos_coordinates[8] - updatePos_coordinates[8] > 5) or (pos_coordinates[8] - updatePos_coordinates[8] < -5) or (pos_coordinates[9] - updatePos_coordinates[9] > 5) or (pos_coordinates[9] - updatePos_coordinates[9] < -5)):     
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: print what your pos_coordinates and len(pos_coordinates) are right before that line ... (not what you think it is ... actually print it )

Comment: It means that `pos_coordinates` or `updatePos_coordinates` has fewer than 9 or 10 elements.

Comment: @JoranBeasley it prints this pos_coordinates = ['start', 'inch', '640', '480', '0', '0', '640', '480', '488', '290', '15', 'teset1', '336', '184', '37', 'eom']
updatePos_coordinates= []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access `updatePos_coordinates[8]` when it doesn't have any elements yet, as it hasn't been changed since you defined it as `updatePos_coordinates = []`.

You should fill `updatePos_coordinates` with default values before the loop.

For example:

```
updatePos_coordinates = ['' for _ in range(16)]
# replace 16 with length of pos_coordinates
```

Alternatively, you could just make both coordinates equal to each other the first time through the loop.

```
if len(updatePos_coordinates) < 16:
    updatePos_coordinates = pos_coordinates[:]

elif pos_coordinates != updatePos_coordinates:
    ...
```

I've also noticed that you are treating the coordinates like integers, when they are actually strings.

Comment: It might, but you should probably use the same type as the elements in `pos_coordinates`. Don't fill it with zeros if `pos_coordinates` contains strings. I've updated my answer.